# i want change activity when static value is 0 or other

Tags: java, android, static

i make the client server in android iwant server change activity when client side the button has clicked

I have a static variable int, I set the value to 0, when the button is clicked it changes its value to 1 and the value 1 must change the activity in another class,but is nothing happen in another class

here my static variable and here is Clientactivity 1

```
public static int CHANGE_ACT=0;
```

this is when user clicked action

```
sendReceive.write(jsonOrderHolder.getBytes());
        CHANGE_ACT = 1;
        Toast.makeText(this, "you clicked"+CHANGE_ACT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and here my other Serveractivity

```
WifiConnectClientActivity wfc = new WifiConnectClientActivity();



  if (wfc.CHANGE_ACT == 0){
        Toast.makeText(WifiPeerConnectActivity.this, "order null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (wfc.CHANGE_ACT == 1){
        startActivity(new Intent(WifiPeerConnectActivity.this, TransactionActivity.class));
    }
```

server activity show the toast but if value is 1 nothing happen in server activity

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please tell in which class you declared CHANGE_ACT  and from where you want to change the value ? Please provide code.

Comment: CHANGE_ACT from clientActivity  i want if button in clientactivity clicked it changes value to 1 and in serverActivity getValue from staticvariable in ClientActivity if value is 1 ,startActivity,,thats a logic when i try it nothing happen